# Boot records messed on dual boot (Win7 and Ubuntu) machine with SSD and HDD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssd, multi-boot, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y570 with two hard drives: SSD and normal HDD both managed by RapidDrive and Windows 7 pre-installed.

First, I have shrunk my 500 GB HDD a little bit to make some place for a Linux installation.
Then I installed Linux Mint 12 to it, also installed grub onto the drive (dev/sdb).

Installation program has not allowed me to install grub on sda. Then I replaced Linux Mint with Ubuntu 12.04 but installed grub onto the SSD (which is dev/sda and was the default-option).

After that I could boot into my Windows, only Ubuntu worked. So I did a research, and tried 
rewriting mbr of Windows into sda1, reinstalling grub, replacing grub2 with grub-legacy, and now I think my partitions table are totally messed. Here is `fdisk -l` output:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 64.0 GB, 64023257088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7783 cylinders, total 125045424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      411647      204800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          411648  1009430959   504509656    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5e5d1cc8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        1979   884389887   442193954+  12  Compaq diagnostics
/dev/sdb2       884391934   976771071    46189569    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       884391936   937705471    26656768   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       937707520   967006207    14649344   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       967008256   976771071     4881408   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I also can't mount any Windows partitions to recover data. And when I open gparted, the whole sda-disk appears unallocated and it states

> can not have a partition outside the disk!

Also the end-sector address of /dev/sda2 confuses me. If I boot from the SSD, it throws some mbr error and won't boot, if I boot from the HDD, I only get the grub bash.

How do I restore the partition tables? I can boot only from a live-cd at the machine.